# statusesService.homeTimeline allways retrieve the same number of tweets

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

statusesService.homeTimeline first parameters its supposed the number of tweets retrieved ,but whatever the number I pass to the method I always get the default number of tweets,20.

```
public class FollowingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView homeList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_following);

        homeList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.homeList);

        TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
        StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();

        statusesService.homeTimeline(200, null, null, null, null, null, null,//always the same number of tweets
                new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {

                        final FixedTweetTimeline timeline = new FixedTweetTimeline.Builder()
                                .setTweets(result.data)
                                .build();
                        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(FollowingActivity.this)
                                .setTimeline(timeline)
                                .build();

                        homeList.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    }
                }
        );


    }
}
```

Comment: The first parameter is not the amount of items to retrieve.